# How do I increase the bond level for buddies?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, you unlock items and accessories via a bond level. Is there a way to increase the bond level? Will it affect other things (it would make sense)?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "other things".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed possible to increase the bond level with your buddies.

**For example:** D-horse, take it on missions and ride with it.

Actively utilizing your buddy will increase the bond level.

In the end it comes down to which buddies you want to increase the bond level on. Decide which ones and bring them on the missions with you.

[image: Bond Level: Quiet]

*In the upper right corner you can see "Diamond Dogs"-icons. These indicate the bond level you have with this particular buddy.*

**TL;DR** : Yes. Bring them on missions with you.

Comment: Have you noticed the bond level decreasing when you neglect buddies for a while?

Comment: @PhilD. I've seen no sign of this. And that's after paying attention to this for a couple hours of playing the game.

Comment: It can go down though, if e.g. you run over D-Dog with a jeep.

Comment: Yes, abusing the D-Dog will ruin your bond level with him. I accidentally threw a magazine at his nose when he walked in front of me while trying to lure a guard, and his bond level decreased. Not sure if petting him has any effect. I am also curious if, for example, the D-Horse gains bond faster if you don't whip him as much (using the speed up function)

Comment: @LucasLeblanc I have whipped D-Horse a lot from the beginning and the bond increased quite fast. I still whip it all the time and it never decreases, I think it's a normal function.